# Actualizar campos de un Form usando php y mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

He estado escribiendo un pequeño script para actualizar campos en mysql desde un form con php.

Pero tengo un inconveniente, cuando intento actualizar el campo desde php utilizando mysqli, no hay cambios en la base de datos. El campo que intento utilizar como parametro para actualizar es un ID de tipo `int`. Sin embargo, cuando intento utilizar un valor de tipo `string` si lo actualiza. No se si hay un problema al actualizar campos de tipo `int` desde php. Tengo dos paginas, son las siguientes:

Este codigo muestra el resultado de mi busqueda y si me funciona bien.

**Search.php**

```
$searchValue=$_GET["txtSearch"]; 

$connection=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$query="select UserID, LastName, FirstName, UserName, Phone from User where UserID='$searchValue'";
$recordset=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($recordset, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{       
    $UserID=$row['UserID'];
    $LastName = $row['LastName'];
    $FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
    $UserName = $row['UserName'];
    $Phone=$row['Phone'];

    echo "<form action='Update.php' method='get'>";

    echo "<input type='text' name='txtUserID' value='$UserID' disabled> <br/> <br/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtLastName' value='$LastName'> <br/> <br/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtFirstName' value='$FirstName'> <br/> <br/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtUserName' value='$UserName'> <br/> <br/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtPhone' value='$Phone'> <br/> <br/>";

    echo "<input type='submit' name='btnUpdate' value='Update Values' />";

    echo "</form>";     

}
```

El problema esta aca, cuando ejecuto la consulta. He estado intentando y no encuento la solucion del problema. ¿Esta incorrecto el query? ¿Hay alguna otra forma de actualizar valores tipo `int` desde php?

Este es el codigo de la otra pagina que deberia hacer la actualizacion.

**Update.php**

```
$userID=$_GET["txtUserID"];
$lastName=$_GET["txtLastName"];
$firstName=$_GET["txtFirstName"];
$userName=$_GET["txtUserName"];
$phone=$_GET["txtPhone"];

$connection=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

$query="UPDATE User SET LastName='$lastName', FirstName='$firstName', UserName='$userName', Phone=$phone
        WHERE UserID=$userID";

$recordset=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "<h1> Succesfull Operation.  </h1>";
```

Si en lugar de utilizar `WHERE UserID=$userID` utilizo                     `WHERE LastName=$lastName` si me va bien la actualizacion.

Comment: Te marca algún error o simplemente no te lo guarda?

Comment: Simplemente no me guarda.

Comment: Ni en la sección de desarrollo?, en la seccion de network que aparece en la petición de update.php?

Comment: Hola @krlosfgx, un campo con un dato int, si se puede actualizar, realmente no se cual pueda ser el problema, pero por lo que veo tu id es una PK y por tal motivo nunca puedes actualizar ese dato...lo que te recomendaría es que trabajes con un ID PK & Auto_increment y que trabajes con otro campo con dato int pero que si tengas la posibilidad de manipularlo. Espero haberme hecho entender, Saludos.

Comment: Hola @krlosfgx. Veo en una respuesta que solucionaron tu problema. ¿Es así o aún tienes problemas? Si aún tienes problemas te agradecería que publicaras el esquema de tu base de datos para poder ayudarte mejor. Puedes usar, por ejemplo, phpmyadmin para exportar la base de datos e indicar "sólo estructura" (esquema). Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

No le esta llegando el valor del `idUsuario` te recomiento que al campo en vez de ponerlo como `disabled` lo coloques como `hidden`:

```
<input type='hidden' name='txtUserID' value='$UserID'>
```

El problema no es el tipo de datos `int` sino que no le llega el valor del `txtUserID`.

Comment: No, el campo phone es de tipo int. He hecho la consulta en el gestor y si me va bien, el inconveniente es con el parametro de WHERE UserID=$userID de la consulta en php.

Comment: pero en la consulta que dices no lo estas actualizando al Id de Usuario, solo en el where estas buscando por este id,por lo tanto tendrías que agregar en el set una asignación con el nuevo id de usuario, que tiene que ser distinto al id que buscas si no te va actualizar por el mismo valor.

Comment: Lo siento, estaba mal planteada la pregunta. Intento actualizar los campos utilizando el ID como parametro en el WHERE. Pero utilizando el userID no me funciona la consulta. Utilizando otro campo que sea de tipo string com oparametro en el WHERE si me funciona.

Comment: no le esta llegando el valor del idUsuario te recomiento que al campo en vez de ponerlo como disabled lo coloques como hidden`:<input type='hidden' name='txtUserID' value='$UserID'>`, el problema no es el tipo de datos int sino q no le llega el valor del id.

Comment: Perfecto! Ese era el inconveniente, no estaba llegando el valor debido a que estaba como disabled. Habia intentado de varias maneras desde mysql, no pense que la solucion estaria en un tag HTML.  Te agradezco :)

Comment: buenisimo entonces.Saludos

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que este respuesta la añadieras como comentario

Comment: no tengo privilegios aun para añadirla como comentario en stackoverflow español.Pero gracias por la recomendación.